# PS Script to export AD Data

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am looking for all accounts that have “(FUR)” in the begging of their AD account description.  I need these for any and all OUs under Office/Users.  All of these accounts that Have “(FUR)” in the description, I need the following exported;

- User Logon Name
- Description
- extensionattribute11

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory;
$creds = Get-Credential
$OUPath = 'OU=Standard Users,OU=NY,OU=users,OU=Offices,DC=US,DC=FLN,DC=NET'
Get-ADUser -Properties Description -Filter "(FUR)" -SearchBase $OUPath
```

This is the error I get:

```
Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: '(FUR)' Error Message: 'syntax
error' at position: '5'. At line:2 char:1
+ Get-ADUser -Properties Description -Filter "(FUR)" -SearchBase $OUPat ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to escape the parenthesis e.g `-Filter "\(FUR\)"`?

Answer (score 2):

When using the `-Filter` parameter, you must pass a string that contains the syntax `propertyName -operator value`.

```
Get-ADUser -Properties Description -Filter "Description -like '(FUR)*'" -SearchBase $OUPath
```

`(FUR)*` would match a value that begins with `(FUR)`. You would need to use `*(FUR)*` if you do not know where `(FUR)` exists within the value.

See [Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps) for a more in-depth description.

Comment: This code works
Get-ADUser -Properties Description -Filter "*" -SearchBase $OUPath

but I need to only pull users that have '(FUR)'  so when I enter 
Get-ADUser -Properties Description -Filter "(FUR)" -SearchBase $OUPath   I get an error

Comment: @JoshuaRomoff But did you try AdminOfThings suggestion?

Comment: no I am sorry I am still new to powershell and Stack Overflow can you please help thank you @nojustme

Comment: `Get-ADUser -Properties Description -Filter "Description -like '(FUR)*'" -SearchBase $OUPath` - Copy/paste.